# Determine if term is Category or Tag

Tags: plugin-development, categories, tags

I am working on a piece of code for my plugin and I am trying to find the best way to pull Terms in to post object. The object will have the usual title, description etc. but it will also need Categories and Tags. The issue I am facing is that if the post type is a custom post type with custom taxonomies (categories and tags), I can't determine which is which.

```
$taxonomy_names = get_object_taxonomies(isset($post_type) ? $post_type : 'post');

$categories = '';

if(!empty($taxonomy_names)) {
   foreach($taxonomy_names as $taxonomy) {

       $category = wp_get_post_terms($id, $taxonomy, array(
            'fields' => 'all'
            )
        );

       print_r($category);

       $categories .= $category[0]->name . ',';

    }
}
```

The above code prints out:

[image]

The top object is category and bottom is a tag - is there any way I could differentiate between these?

Answer (score 0):

Solution below :)

I when through how WordPress determines if the term is category or tag. I found that there is an attribute called 'hierarchical' - it went down the hill from there.

I found a nice little function called `is_taxonomy_hierarchical()` and I fixed the issue with two if statements.

```
if(is_taxonomy_hierarchical($taxonomy)) {
                            if(isset($term[0]->name)) {
                                if($term[0]->parent > 0) {
                                    $categories .= $parent . ' > ' . $term[0]->name . ',';
                                } else {
                                    $categories .= $term[0]->name . ',';
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if(!is_taxonomy_hierarchical($taxonomy)) {
                            if(isset($term[0]->name)) {
                                $tags .= $term[0]->name . ',';
                            }
                        }
```

Hope this will be helpful to someone in future!